# Searching Posts Programmatically in a Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, search, sql

If I navigate to `Posts -> All Posts` in a Wordpress install, there's a Search Box in the upper right hand corner.  Entering terms in this box and clicking the Search Posts button will perform a search.

Does Wordpress provide a hook, function, or other API that would allow me to programmatically perform the same (or a similar) search?  i.e. I pass in a string as terms and get back a PHP array of results without needing to write any SQL myself.

If not, does anyone here know where in the Wordpress core code the above search happens? (so I cam mimic the behavior as best as possible)

Thank you!

Comment: try this : `$posts = get_posts(["s" => "string to search"]);`. you will find more informations in the codex : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts

Comment: @mmm if that's an answer you should post it as one so it can be marked correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Per comments above from [mmm](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/74311/mmm)

Try this

```
$posts = get_posts(["s" => "string to search"]);
```

Also, Covering the `get_posts` API is a bit beyond a single StackExchange answer, but if you want to dive deep you'll find more informations [in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts).